# How to show Modal in rails from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

In my Rails application I'm using several modals and that's all working great if using a link_to helper on a page. So when user clicks it opens the modal.
There is one use case where i need to show a modal directly from the controller so without user interaction (on first visit), how to do this?

Comment: I think it will be easier to answer once we see some code you have. How do you handle "when user clicks it opens the modal" ? Is that with AJAX or HTML+JS loaded on the page and inside JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is only responsible for opening the right HTML page, it doesn't concern itself with the visibility of objects (like modals) on that page. So you have to set an instance variable in the controller like `@show_modal = true` (or maybe there is an existing condition that you can check for) and then in the view you add something like

```
<% if @show_modal %>
  <script>$('#my_modal').show()</script>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if @show_modal %>
  <script>$('#my_modal_link').click()</script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a way to do it and I agree, but as my previous comment on the initial post, there are multiple ways to handle this. You might have a setup with a controller action which renders JS (I think this is the right approach), then where you keep the business logic can change. Without seeing any code, I don't know how he thought about having the modal on the page.

Comment: @radubogdan if the controller renders js its still done in the view. Which makes it a view concern. The less you can involve your controllers in the state of the view the better your code organization will be.